# Define a classes possible properties

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

I don't want to turn off an code inspections, but is there a way I can define what class properties could be defined, so when using methods within the class I'm not getting `Unresolved variable` warning?

[image]

I would use TypeScript however I can't do that right now. Is there another way? There's many properties that can be set or not set.

I can remove this within the constructor by defining what value can contain:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show code as text, not as pictures of text. See [ask], where it says, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**." (emphasis in the original)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I used screenshots so the text that my IDE can be seen as this is the subject of the question, not the code itself.

Comment: Well, search engines and blind people can't do much with "enter image description here", which is the alt text those images have, and is the only description they have for the images. I'm not sure how copying the text of the JSDoc (for instance) would make the question *less* easy to understand to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define class properties and write jsdoc like this:

```js
class Base {
  /**
   * @type {boolean}
   */

  disableReset;

  /**
   * @param {boolean} disableReset
   */
  constructor(disableReset) {
    this.disableReset = disableReset;
  }
  reset() {
    if (this.disableReset) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

[image]